# compare 2 spreadsheets like recordsets? possible?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, recordset

I was wondering what the best way to compare 2 sheets are in Excel.
Now im actually getting the data from Access and exporting it to a Spreadsheet. From there i wish to interrogate it and find out the differences in records. Now the catch is its not a straight compare, information in SHEET 1-cell A1 might exist in SHEET 2 but be in cell A3, so therefore i want it to mark it as similar. (most of the stuff i have come accross assumes that data is the same if its in the same cells only). When this was planned it was imagined that you could put the data into a recordset and itterate through each record (so each row on SHEET 1) and compare with other recordset (rows of SHEET 2)

Bascially, can i put data into a recordset in Excel? or something similar?

Thanks,

Comment: Does each row have a unique id, or is there some combination of fields which can be relied on to uniquely identify a row in the database table ?

Comment: And by compare do you mean compare values, formulae or values/formulae?

Comment: ...... and please do not cross post your questions to [multiple forums](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=605348)

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want using `ADO` to get a recordset from excel

Search SO  for `[Excel] ado`, there are many many questions dealing with this